# Need to generate EDMX files and compile them

Tags: c#, dynamic, code-generation, compilation, edmx

My question might be little bit different or basic for advanced users here.

I have a web application which is customizable by administrators. This means, the admin can add new table schema  or edit table columns, add new table columns etc. These changes are mapped to our logical objects (much similar to EDMX) which is published after the change. While publishing we generate Stored procedures with necessary changes that are required.

From UI we use these Logical objects to connect DB (using COM which understands the mapping and executes appropriate sprocs and views etc). Now i am thinking to use EF for replacing the Logical objects model which we are having currently. I can create the EDMX files (csdl,msl, ssdl, cs files) dynamically but i am not sure how to compile them and package the classes into DLL dynamically. This means, when i click the button the all edmx related files will be created and DLLs must be created based on CS files and the website must be able to access the new changes in the code.

Can you help me how to automatically and dynamically compile the cs files. I will not have the source code of other files (like default.aspx and others) at customer's end.

Thanks
Albert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bepenfriends - rather than attempting a CSC from a shell, consider using a CSharpCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile.

One thing to be careful of: if you compile code and then try to compile it again, you may lock up on the assembly that was created.  For this I created an AsyncCompiler which creates a new AppDomain, compiles in there, and then unloads the AppDomain.

It's some pretty hairy code but I'm doing this (generating the AEF XML files, generating code from them, and then compiling everything into an assembly) and it works well.  The only thing I don't have quite right is dynamically importing stored procedures - my SSDL has them but not the CSDL or MSL.  The search for a solution led me here.

I hope the keywords here are enough to set you off in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks TonyG, Will it be possible to provide code snippet (may be the skeleton) of your asynccompiler. Yes your keywords are leading me to a lot of places.

Comment: Can you outline what you have done in your compiler? I find myself in similar situation. I'm trying to extract the .csdl, .msl content from the edmx itself and embed them into the assembly.

Comment: Unfortunately I did that four years ago and haven't re-visited it in a while. So my memory is useless to you at this point, so sorry. But it was some very cool code that I might dig up later. If you are working on a company project then perhaps I can put some time on the clock for this (PM me), otherwise I can't prioritize any more effort. The issue with stored procs was that it simply wasn't supported in the version of EF that I was using but it should be now. Wish I could help more here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have a definitive answer for you just yet - but two potential solutions you could look into, possibly in the near future:

1) There's a set of CodeSmith templates called [PLINQO](http://www.plinqo.com/) which generate your Linq-to-SQL model (DBMX) and its associated *.cs files from your database. I asked them about Entity Framework support myself, and they confirmed to be working on it - so maybe they'll have that some time soon.

Since those are code and model generation templates, you could definitely take those for Linq-to-SQL and tweak them for EDMX, too. A bit of work, but definitely possible. Once you have the *.cs files and the *.edmx model, you can generate a resulting assembly from it using the CSC (C#) command-line compiler that's installed on every machine which has .NET installed.

2) With .NET 4, the new Entity Framework 4 will include [T4 templates](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/12/05/t4-templates-in-entity-framework-4.aspx) (another code generation technology) which will allow you to customize your code generation. Same story applies here - you could externally generate your EDMX model and associated *.cs files for the classes and generate an assembly on the fly from those templates.

See another [blog post](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/customizing-edm-code-gen-in-ef4/) on that topic, and you should find lots of information when gooling (or binging) or "EF4 T4 templates".

Hope that helps at least a little bit!

Comment: Hi, I am able to create the EDMX classes and CSDL files for my DB separately. There is no problem in doing that. My problem is that, whenever i change the EDMX (from my custom framework) I need to compile those classes into DLL (provided i have the folder permissions for doing the same). from a webpage button click. 

I am struck in this place (compiling) not on the generation of classes.I am not sure how to call the CSC(in server) from website.